# How StringBuffer delete works in java

Tags: java, stringbuffer

In java, the StringBuffer function will work like this
`str="hello"`  like it is specified the `str.delete(1,3)`.
 I wanted to know how it works, like how it takes the position

```
class StringBufferExample4 {  
  public static void main(String args[]) {  
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("Hello");  
    sb.delete(1,3);  
    System.out.println(sb); 
  }  
}
```

it gives the output

> Hlo

How?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: I have not read

Comment: @devd If you have a question about a method/class, the documentation should be the first place you look. It will answer 99% of your questions. The Java Docs are generally excellent.

Comment: Note that in almost all cases you should be using `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: *"I have not read"* - you **should have** read! The javadoc tells you what the method does.  If you *really* want to know how it works, look at the source code.  And please, please, please do some research before you ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> StringBuffer delete() method removes the characters in a substring of
>   this StringBuffer. The substring begins at the specified start and
>   extends to the character at index end - 1 or to the end of the
>   StringBuffer if no such character exists.

from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/stringbuffer_delete.htm

Comment: How to specify the start and end of the deleting portion

Comment: As you just wrote in your question above: str.delete(1,3) - '1' is the start and '3' is the end of deleting position.

Comment: Than how come only two char is deleting

Comment: start − The beginning index, is inclusive, while end − the ending index, is exclusive. Simply speaking, str.delete(1,3) will delete 2 characters at index 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you very much Serj Ardovic